# Unfair split of workload among spark executors

Tags: apache-spark

I am currently using `spark` to process documents. I have two servers at my disposal (`innov1` and `innov2`) and I am using `yarn` as the resource manager.

The first step is to gather the paths of the files from a database, filter them, repartition them and persist them in a `RDD[String]`. However, I can't manage to have a fair sharing of the persist among all the executors:

[persisted RDD memory taken among executors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iChrc.png)

and this lead to the executors **not** doing the same amount of work after that:

[Work done by each executors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvhn7.png) (do not care about the 'dead' here, it's another problem)

And this happens randomly, sometimes it's `innov1` that takes all the persist, and then only executors on `innov1` work (but it tends to be `innov2` in general). Right now, each time two executors are on `innov1`, I just kill the job to relaunch, and I pray for them to be on `innov2` (which is utterly stupid, and break the goal of using spark).

What I have tried so far (and that didn't work):

1. make the driver sleep 60 seconds before the loading from the database (maybe `innov1` takes more time to wake up?)
2. add `spark.scheduler.minRegisteredResourcesRatio=1.0` when I submit the job (same idea than above)
3. persist with replication x2 (idea from this [link](http://www.ccri.com/2015/08/17/cloud-computing-with-spark-using-all-your-executors/)), hoping that some of the block would be replicated on innov1

   Note for point 3, sometimes it was persisting a replication on the same executor (which is a bit counter intuitive), or even weirder, not replicated at all (`innov2` is not able to communicate with `innov1`?).

I am open to any suggestion, or link to similar problems I would have missed.

**Edit:**

I can't really put code here, as it's part of my company's product. I can give a simplified version however:

```
val rawHBaseRDD : RDD[(ImmutableBytesWritable, Result)] = sc
 .newAPIHadoopRDD(...)
 .map(x => (x._1, x._2)) // from doc of newAPIHadoopRDD
 .repartition(200)
 .persist(MEMORY_ONLY)

val pathsRDD: RDD[(String, String)] = rawHBaseRDD
 .mapPartitions {
  ...
  extract the key and the path from ImmutableBytesWritable and 
  Result.rawCells()
  ...
 }
 .filter(some cond)
 .repartition(200)
 .persist(MEMORY_ONLY)
```

For both persist, everything is on `innov2`. Is it possible that it's because the data are only on `innov2`? even if it's the case, I would assume that repartition help to share the rows between `innov1` and `innov2`, but it doesn't happen here.

Comment: So we need more information. First of all how many cores and how much memory is allocated?

Comment: I use 3 executors, 10 cores and 20 Gb of RAM each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately (fortunately?) the problem solved by itself today. I assume it is not spark related as I hadn't modified the code until the resolution.

It's probably due to the complete reboot of all services with Ambari (even if I am not 100% sure, because I already tried this before), as it's the only "major" change that happened today.

Answer (score 0):

Your persisted data set is not very big - some ~100MB according to your screenshot. You have allocated 10 cores with 20GB of memory, so the 100MB fits easily into the memory of a single executor and that is basically what is happening.

In other words, you have allocated many more resources than are actually needed, so Spark just randomly picks the subset of resources that it needs to complete the job. Sometimes those resources happen to be on one worker, sometimes on another and sometimes it uses resources from both workers.

You have to remember that to Spark, it makes no difference if all resources are placed on a single machine or on a 100 different machines - as long as you are not trying to use *more* resources than available (in which case you would get an OOM).

Comment: I could live with that, my problem is that the computation done on this data afterwards is heavy, and the executors without persisted data are  processing a tiny part of the partition at the beginning only. With what you said, the problem would come from a problem in the distribution of the rows not the persiste, wouldn't it ?

Comment: Hmm... if the data you need persisted isn't that big in general, you might want to consider simply broadcasting it, so all your executors have it readily available for further processing.